# ArchLinux: No screens found after update to 4.9.32

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

after updating linux-lts to 4.9.32, my laptop boots to a black screen. (I reproduce this problem with any version 4.9.32+).
Booting my computer to command line and starting Xorg manually, the error "No screens found" appears.

[lspci -v](https://pastebin.com/RWymtnZ2)

nvidia-lts and bumblebee packages installed.

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d

- [10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf](https://pastebin.com/XCHLcZ1U)
- [10-quirks.conf](https://pastebin.com/YSsUxv6d)
- [40-libinput.conf](https://pastebin.com/ZXNRYnwy)
- [70-synaptics.conf](https://pastebin.com/9MT1awnY)

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

- [10-monitor.conf](https://pastebin.com/b6ezCgXJ)
- [20-intel.conf](https://pastebin.com/wdNhbd6L)
- [20-nvidia.conf](https://pastebin.com/G92NDfhB)

working 4.9.31-1-lts

- [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/0sE9CMEB)
- [Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/3cTAQjQ2)
- [Xorg.8.log](https://pastebin.com/mbviKeZg)

not working 4.9.36-1-lts

- [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/mzmt2u8y)
- [Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/YFqrdYER)
- [Xorg.8.log](https://pastebin.com/97YUvmen)

Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the content of your `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` ?

Comment: Xorg configuration files added to the question.

Comment: Can you explain what nvidia does or should do ? Did you follow the wikis https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Installation && https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA ? Cause your logs say that you're loading intel not nvidia ...

Comment: @funilrys I don't remember if I followed those particular wikis when I set up my system. I checked those wikis and I found out that the config about nvidia was missing. I added the 20-nvidia.conf, but nothing is changed. I also checked the Xorg.0.log: with my currently working system the nvidia is loaded properly, so I have updated the log in the question. What do you mean with "what nvidia should do?"? Thank you for your help so far...